# Facebook Graph API: Creating app test-user friends that are not app users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-test-users

I want to test Facebook App Invite for friends that are not app users.

I need to create friends for a Facebook app test user but I don't want those friends to already be app users.

Currently App Invite shows me all my friends which happen to be app test users.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several ways to do that:

- Simply don’t set the option “Authorize Test Users for This App?” when creating them via app dashboard; or
- create them via API – when doing that, you can specify if they should have the app already “installed” or not as well; or
- log in as them on Facebook, and remove the app from their settings.

Comment: What is the HTTP API to create a test user through API?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v4.0/app/accounts/test-users